# How do you even see the focus area rectangle when in dark?

Tags: camera-basics, viewfinder, focus-point-selection, focus-point-indicators

I was reading the manual for my camera and well they have a rectangular kind of area that they show in viewfinder and those little squares as focus point and how to change those focus points.
But the problem is when I am in dark areas like shooting at night, then I can't even see the black borders of this focus rectangle or those square focus points at night? Is there some sort of night mode that can paint the borders with something other than black?
My camera is `Nikon D-610`

Comment: Related: photo.stackexchange.com/questions/30076/how-do-i-make-the-focus-point-indicators-stay-long-enough-to-select-on-the-canon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the manual](http://download3.nikonimglib.com/archive1/3PBoc00MJ7vb00PxKru74a9gED26/D610_NT(En)01.pdf) of your camera (page 222), AF point illumination is controlled by custom setting **a4**.

It can be set to On, Off or Auto.  When set to Auto, the camera decides whether it needs to illuminate points based on the light levels.  It will only briefly illuminate the markings on a half-press of the shutter.